# Date Format localization through localizationsDelegates?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble implementing internationalization of DateFormat.

I use the below code to get the date formatted:

```
var time = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(item['time'] * 1000);
${DateFormat('EEEE, MMMM d').format(time)}
```

returns `Friday, February 6`

Changing my device to another language, continues to return `Friday, February 6`.

The internationalization of other Strings within the app (those manually translated) are working as intended.

Below is the code which initializes `localizationsDelegates`.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp();

  @override
  MyAppStateful createState() => MyAppStateful();
}

class MyAppStateful extends State<MyApp> {
  MyAppStateful();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: supportedLocales,
      localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
        for (var i in supportedLocales) {
          if (i.languageCode == locale.languageCode) {
            return i;
          }
        }
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
      home: isX ? Y() : Z(),
    );
  }
}
```

My question is two fold:

1) How can I have a translated DateFormat of the current date?

2) Is it possible to localize the DateFormat formatting? Instead of forcing it to be: `DateFormat('EEEE, MMMM d').format(time)}` have it be flexible to locale?
E.g.: In the US it's `Weekday, Month Day`, but in France it's `Weekday Day Month`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I don't know about second fold, but for the first you can use smth like this:

```
var time = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(item['time'] * 1000);
${DateFormat('EEEE, MMMM d', Localizations.localeOf(context).toString()).format(time)}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to solving point #2 is using DateFormat's integrated patterns:

`DateFormat.yMMMMd(Localizations.localeOf(context).toString()).format(time)` returns the correct formatting wrt to user's locale.

Comment: This used with `easy_localization` package did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Just add this line in the method that listens to each time the locale changes**

```
Intl.defaultLocale = languageCode;
```

from the package: https://pub.dev/packages/intl